# Migrate from ADO.NET to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have my project set up on ASP.NET MVC 4 using ADO.NET.

But I think that my Data Access Layer is not upto the mark. In my company, the data fetching works this way - First the indexes of all the columns of the query result are stored in variables. And then, values are fetched using those index variables. 
It saves times because `DataReader["Name"]` will be slower than `DataReader[0]`

But this approach makes my dev speed slow (mapping variables etc). Plus, while fetching a single record, it actually does double the work - First it gets indexes, then it fetches data, instead of just fetching the data.

I am thinking to migrate to EF.

Whatever documentation I have seen about EF, I am interpreting it in a way that, with EF, my already written Stored Procs will be of no use.

Is it so, if I migrate to EF now, I will have to write code for all my CRUD operations again?

Comment: It is possible to use stored procedures in EF. Depending on how your SPs are structured you might be able to use them with EF.

Comment: thanks @HåkanFahlstedt doesnt using SPs defeat the purpose of EF?

Comment: Well, the possibility to use SPs in EF is there for situations like yours, when there is already a database with SPs. If you should start from no database, there is probably no need to use SPs at all, but there are always exceptions from a rule. And even in this scenario, when using SPs, you get many OR-mapper benefits from using EF.

Comment: thanks @HåkanFahlstedt , what benefits will I get in my case?..sorry if i m bothering you :P

Comment: You get the OR-mapper benefits, instead of going through several steps to e.g read data, you just create a dbcontext and there you have all your data presented as collections of objects.

Comment: @Lakshay are you asking how to use SPs in EF ?

Comment: Yes @meda if I can get a sample oroject, that would be really helpful

Comment: you can definitely use SPs with  EF , i think its even better becuase its less code, but ill write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different way to call a stored procedure. I personaly prefer to use `EDMX` files.

There are only few steps:

- **Import Stored Procedure**

[image]

- **Create function Import**

Here is an example where I wrapped a `function import` into a method:

```
    private static List<GetEmployees_Result> GetEmployeeList()
    {
        using (var db = new DBEntities())
        {
            //do some crazy Linq
            ObjectResult<GetEmployees_Result> listOfEmployees = db.GetEmployees("USA");
            return listOfEmployees.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Thats it, now compare that with the tones of ADO.NET code you need to write to do the same thing!

<kbd>[SAMPLE PROJECT](https://mega.co.nz/#!2UASwLQA!go7bRL0rsIeULyzdivSU34yO11pj-YfE-d9IGVzv3J0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @meda .. Can anyone suggest me a sample project

Comment: @Lakshay I added a sample project for you bro

Answer (score 1):

You might be doing it for the wrong reasons.

If the performance reason between `DataReader["name"]` and `DataReader[0]` makes a noticeable difference in your project, adding another layer of indirection (Entity Framework) will probably make performance worse.

However, I rather assume that this difference is *not really* relevant in your case, and your company is doing it out of a misdirected desire to micro-optimize.

My advise is to try EF, try using DataTables ([DataRow.Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) provides type-safe access to query results), compare it with your current approach and then choose whatever makes your development life easier. In most cases, the data access time will largely dominate any "column name lookup" time, so I would not worry too much about that.